# Excel VBA & Access Query - Insert data into Table from another Table and data from Excel sheet

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I am using Excel VBA to transfer data from Access table 1 to table 2 with Insert Into query. Access query below work fine:

```
    "INSERT INTO " & _
        "tblTable2 ([Col_1], [Col_2], [Col_3]) " & _
    "SELECT " & _
        "tblTable1.[Data_1], tblTable1.[Data_2], tblTable1.[Data_3] " & _
    "FROM " & _
        "tblTable1 " & _
    "WHERE " & _
        "tblTable1.[Data_1] = " & Sheet1.Range("D3").Value
```

Than Table 2 was added new column (Col_4) which the data will be from excel sheet directly. I do written the code (shown below) and it is not work.

```
    "INSERT INTO " & _
        "tblTable2 ([Col_4], [Col_1], [Col_2], [Col_3]) " & _
    "VALUES (" & sheet2.Range("F1").value & ", " & _        
       "(SELECT " & _
            "tblTable1.[Data_1], tblTable1.[Data_2], tblTable1.[Data_3] " & _
        "FROM " & _
            "tblTable1 " & _
        "WHERE " & _
            "tblTable1.[Data_1] = " & Sheet1.Range("D3").Value & "))"
```

Is any code above was inaccurate?

Comment: Yes, your SQL is incorrect as you cannot combine `VALUES()` with `SELECT` in append queries (use only one of either). And is it just one scalar value from Excel to import? Or a column of values?

Comment: @Parfait Could he create a calculated column in his select? `"SELECT & " & sheet2.Range("F1").value & " AS [Data_4], tblTable1.[Data_1], tblTable1.[Data_2], tblTable1.[Data_3]"`

Comment: @Parfait, It is just a single value from excel sheet.

Comment: @ThomasInzina, your solution is work. Thanks

Comment: Cool...glad that I could help.

Comment: Yes @ThomasInzina as OP confirms. However, that one scalar value will repeat for every row in table of `SELECT` statement if that is OP's intended result.

Comment: It seemed to be what he was looking to do.